# Override property on AbpRoleBase class

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to extend the **RolePermissionSetting** class with additional properties the thing is that this class is declared in abstract **AbpRoleBase class**, which is used across the framework is there a way to accomplish this without generating a different **AbpPermissions** table in the DB.

Here is the piece of code:

```
public abstract class AbpRoleBase : FullAuditedEntity<int>, IMayHaveTenant{

..
public virtual ICollection<RolePermissionSetting> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding **AbpRoleBase** or extending **RolePermissionSetting** or doing something to **AbpPermissions**? You mention all 3 in contradicting ways.

Comment: I tried to extend RolePermissionSetting, but I didn't find a way to force all the core classes to use the new one. About overriding AbpRoleBase directly could be a solution the thing is that my Role class inherit from AbpRole<User>(ZeroModule) which override AbpRoleBase, I'm afraid that if I replace that class with my own, EF will generate a new table in the model then I'll have two Role Tables.

Comment: EF will not generate a new table, but add a `Discriminator` column, which should be fine. `AbpRole` implements, not overrides, `AbpRoleBase`. You can safely override `Permissions` property in [Role.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/Authorization/Roles/Role.cs).

Comment: Thanks @aaron. I'll try your suggestion also I found that adding the custom fields to Role class instead of RolePermissionSetting kind of work for what I'm trying to do. Thank you very much for your help, have a great day.

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: Yes, man, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my Role class inherit from AbpRole(ZeroModule) which override AbpRoleBase, I'm afraid that if I replace that class with my own, EF will generate a new table in the model then I'll have two Role Tables.

EF will not generate a new table, but add a `Discriminator` column, which should be fine.

`AbpRole` implements, not overrides, `AbpRoleBase`. You can safely override `Permissions` property in [Role.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/Authorization/Roles/Role.cs).